# Execute an method on a Ajax post request

Tags: php, angularjs, methods

Im doing an post request with ajax in angular like this:

```
angular.module("gameApp").controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/test.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});
```

As you can see, I'm refering to lib/test.php as the URL, where the data is handled. However, I want to refer to a method in test.php, and handle the data in the method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax only lets you specify a URL.

It is up to the server side code to translate that URL into what you want.

Create a new PHP script that includes the function you want to call and then calls it. Use the URL to that script instead of `test.php`.

Comment: So I must build a route handling? Like the one in for example Zend framework?

Comment: That is one approach to it.